# Expose Custom Item Field to SCA Webstore?

Tags: netsuite, suitecommerce

How can I expose a custom item field webstore side? I have created a custom item field `custitem_promotional_price`. I now need to access that value in one of my backbone views.

So my view needs to access this property like so:

```
var promoPrice = this.model.get('custitem_promotional_price');
```

Right now that property is not coming through in the item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the custitem_promotional_price field in your fieldsets. In the Details area.